# AngularJs - Determining the next location's route in $locationChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Recently I found out about the undocumented $locationChangeStart event in AngularJS when trying to determine where in the framework I should be redirecting users to the login page if their session is invalid.

I'm listening for the event using the following:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {
   // Logic goes here
});
```

where `nextLocation` and `previousLocation` are absolute urls to locations within the app.

My question is this: Does AngularJS expose the ability to be able to match a url against a route, much like its internal routing engine does to see if an absolute URL matches a defined route?

If not, what would be the best way to detect a route based on an absolute URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I located the relevant source code lines in the AngularJS github project. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c9c3f718e2564a6cc13f958a777ebb4ba9ce5de5/src/ngRoute/route.js#L369) is the function that it uses to match the URL to a route:

Since this functionality is not exposed by Angular I decided to come up with a rudimentary way of matching the URL to a route since the routes I was matching were relatively simple compared to implementing the same route matching that Angular does.

It ain't pretty, but it works..

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you use $location.path() within the event callback, you can get a much cleaner route, so that's another way to do it.

Comment: ^ but the $location.path() seems to be returning location for "current", not next one?

Comment: I am very curious to see your solution.   Did you modify the parseRoute() function a bit?

Comment: I no longer have access to the code that I was working on when I asked this question. I am certain that I didn't have to modify the angular source though.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa No, in `$locationChangeStart` it returns path or url for the next route (where you want to go)